# jQuery remove class but go to the link first

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have a navigation menu that I need to hide after a link has been clicked. Here's my code:

```
jQuery("#nav a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = jQuery('body');
    if (body.hasClass('display-header'))
    {
        body.removeClass('display-header');
        jQuery('.overlay').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

The remove class works fine but the link won't go to the right section. (Imagine a single page with anchor links.)

How would you go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: So then why use `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: What he means to say is `e.preventDefault()` will also stop the browser moving to a bookmark anchor.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I removed the prevent default and all is good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the:

e.preventDefault();

and see if that helps.

from the documnetation :
[api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

"For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL. We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event."

Also, if you could provide a full HTML & javascript example that reproduces your issue - it would help greatly !

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I removed the prevent default and all is good :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should try to use `e.stopPropagation()` for do what you want.

Read this answer: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

See you.

Comment: This would depend solely on what was around the anchor, but there is no obvious reason to use `stopPropagation` here. Just removing `preventdefault()` would likely suffice.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I removed the prevent default and all is good :)